# How can I take a reference to specific hash value in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, reference, dereference

How do I create a reference to the value in a specific hash key.  I tried the following but $$foo is empty.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
$hash->{1} = "one";
$hash->{2} = "two";
$hash->{3} = "three";

$foo = \${$hash->{1}};
$hash->{1} = "ONE";

#I want "MONEY: ONE";
print "MONEY: $$foo\n";
```

Comment: If your hash keys are all positive integers, you should probably be using an array.

Answer (score 8):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $hash;

$hash->{1} = "one";
$hash->{2} = "two";
$hash->{3} = "three";

my $foo = \$hash->{1};
$hash->{1} = "ONE";
print "MONEY: $$foo\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

Turn on strict and warnings and you'll get some clues as to what's going wrong.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hash = { a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 };
my $a = \$$hash{a};
my $b = \$hash->{b};

print "$$a $$b\n";
```

In general, if you want to do things with slices <strike>or taking refs</strike>, you've got to use the old style, piled sigil syntax to get what you want.  You may find the [References Quick Reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927) handy, if you don't recall the piled sigil syntax details.

**update**

As **murugaperumal** points out, you can do `my $foo = \$hash->{a};`  I could swear I tried that and it didn't work (to my surprise).  I'll chalk it up to being fatigue making me extra foolish.

Answer (score 3):

a classic, and yet the examples don't seem to be complete until you illustrate it both ways

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hash = { abc => 123 };
print $hash->{abc} . "\n"; # 123 , of course

my $ref = \$hash->{abc};
print $$ref . "\n"; # 123 , of course

$hash->{abc} = 456;
print $$ref . "\n"; # 456 , change in the hash reflects in the $$ref

$$ref = 789;
print $hash->{abc} . "\n"; # 789 , change in the $$ref also reflects in the hash
```

PS: despite being an old topic, I decided to throw my two cents, since I saw I've visited this same question before